Upgrade 22.04LTS to 24.04 problem: PipeWire is held back in favor of pulse-audio
My failed attempt to upgrade my NUC i5 system from Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS (KDE desktop) to 24.04.1 LTS has - amongst 102 other held-back modules - this message in the apt.log file:

... 
Considering pulseaudio:amd64** 10 as a solution to pipewire-alsa:amd64 0
MarkKeep pipewire-alsa:amd64 < none -/> 1.0.5-1ubuntu1 @un uN Ib > FU=0 
Holding Back pipewire-alsa:amd64 rather than change pulseaudio:amd64 

I do want to switch to the new PipeWire as default audio server.
Is it wise to make a fresh install of 24.04? Or try to fix all upgrade problems and try switching to PipeWire afterward?

If you want to learn from the experience, then try to fix. If you just want it to work immediately, then reinstall.

In mean time, I decided to forget the upgrade and go for a new installation. Now I can make my own stuff operational in the environment that I work in for the next couple (3?) of years.

This upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 has been unusually buggy. I think you made the correct decision. Even my fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 was buggy by my standards. Fortunately there was nothing buggy that I couldn't fix though.

Thanks. I will keep my 'production' laptop on 22.04LTS for some time (months, years) until I really need to move over to 24.04LTS. And try the crucial parts first on this NUC machine and/or a virtual machine
